# how to apply formula in excel cell without the value being shown

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2010

The question may be a little difficult to comprehend and i cannot find better way to out it across. So here i am explaining with an image
[image]

I have a formula in G8. I want to apply the formula to 500 rows.

But when i drag.. i get this
[image]

What I want is that the formula should be present for all the 500 rows.. but zero should not be visible initially. That is, after I enter value in G9, value should be calculated in G9

I know that we can hide the zeros from the option of excel..but that does not serve my purpose. Is there any way to achieve what i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type this in your result cells.

```
=IF(A11+B11 = 0, "", A11+B11)
```

Here A11+B11 is my formula to get the summation of A11 and B11.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please also tell me how to do it in case of text. For column H in the above case

Comment: I assumend that `working_days` is a variable. So `=IF(F9/working_days=0,"",F9/working_days)`, Is this not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your formula to check if F8 is empty:

```
=IF(F8<>"",F8/Working_Days,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

control-tilde

It changes from "display answer" view to "display formula" view

Links:

- http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2386995,00.asp
- http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/show-formulas-in-cells.php